# What does Hessian in Security / Certificate / SSL Context mean?

Tags: web-services, security, ssl-certificate, activesync, hessian

I am getting an error message that hessian has an issue with active sync Connection.  What does hessian in an SSL-Certificate Context? Is it used for handshake?

Comment: More Infos what hessian does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_(Web_service_protocol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hessian is not an SSL concept. It is a [web service protocol](http://hessian.caucho.com/). You did not provide enough info, but my guess is your server certificate can't be validated on the client when connecting to the service.